# How to call on an objects property value outside of the object maker

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to make an equation for player damage that uses the monsters defense as a calculation. Since each monster has a different defense value I do not know how to code it to change based on the selected monster. Here is what I tried.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t743gzxm/)

```
var playerGold = 0;
var playerExp = 0;
var playerLvl = 1;
var expNeeded = 10;
var playerHP = 10;
var playerATK = 1;
var playerDEF = 1;
var playerSPD = 1;


function Monster(name, exp, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {
    this.name = name;
    this.exp = exp;
  this.gold = gold;
  this.hp = hp;
  this.atk = atk;
  this.def = def;
  this.spd = spd;
  // Method definition
  this.implement = function() {
    var monsterList = document.getElementById('monsterList');
    var opt = document.createElement('OPTION'); // Creating option
    opt.innerText = this.name; // Setting innertText attribute
    monsterList.appendChild(opt); // appending option to select element
  }
  var playerDam = function () {
    var playerDamage = Math.round(playerATK - this.def);
  }
  // Method execution
  this.implement();
}

var fly = new Monster("fly", 1, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1);
var mouse = new Monster("mouse", 2, 3, 10, 2, 0, 2);
var rat = new Monster("rat", 4, 5, 20, 4, 2, 2);
var rabidChihuahua = new Monster("rabid chihuahua", 6, 8, 35, 6, 1, 4);
var bulldog = new Monster("bulldog", 10, 14, 60, 10, 4, 1);

$('#battleButton').click(function() {  
    playerDam();
  $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + playerDamage + " damage");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want, is to :
- save a reference to `this` in the `Monster` class (as `self` for example)
- save a reference to each `Monster` object in a `data` attribute of the `option` element.

```
function Monster(name, exp, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {
  var self = this;
  /* ...*/
  this.implement = function() {
    /* ... */
    // we save the Monster object (self) in the 
    // <option></option> data attribute 'monster'
    $(opt).data('monster', self)
  }

  // and your playerDam function becomes:
  this.playerDam = function () {
    self.playerDamage = Math.round(playerATK - this.def);
    return self.playerDamage;
  }
}
```

When the user click the button, you retrieve the current selected value, and get the data attribute :

```
monsterEl = $('#monsterList option:selected');
// we retrieve the monster selected from the <option></option> data attribute
monster = monsterEl.data('monster')
$('#dam')
  .html("You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage");
```

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t743gzxm/1/)

**Edit**

You have a list of monsters, if you just do:

```
var opt = document.createElement('OPTION'); // Creating option
opt.innerText = this.name;
```

Then you don't save the monster, but just the monster's name.

So you have to keep a reference to the monster object in each `option` element.

One way to do this is to use [`data-attributes`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) whose purpose are to store an object with a name (here I chose `monster` but it could be any string), that you could retrieve later.

When you create a new monster like var `fly = new Monster("fly", 1, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1)`, this will create an `<option data-monster="you monster object"></option>` element (the data-monster will not show in the source, but trust me, it's there), containing the `Monster` object with all its properties (name, hp, exp...).

When you click the button, jQuery will get the selected option and retrieve the data with the key `monster`:

```
// get the selected option via CSS selector
monsterEl = $('#monsterList option:selected')
// get the associated Monster via the .data('monster') method
monster = monsterEl.data('monster')
// now you can invoke method on the monster variable
console.log(monster.name ) // 'fly'
console.log(monster.hp ) // 5
```

Now as for the `playerDam()` function :

```
var self = this
this.playerDamage = 0;
this.playerDam = function () {
    self.playerDamage = Math.round(playerATK - self.def);
    return self.playerDamage;
}
```

You are assigning the `playerDam` function to the Monster function scope (`this`).
To access the Monster scope inside the function, you have to use a trick and use a variable (here `self`, but could be any variable name) to store the Monster scope beforehand. Then you can access it from inside the `playerDam` function.

You could also have used a method on the prototype to save up memory:

```
Monster.prototype.playerDam = function() {
    // 'this' is the now the Monster class scope
    this.playerDamage = Math.round(playerATK - this.def);
    return this.playerDamage;
}
```

I hope I was clear, this mix a lot of different concepts together, maybe other could explain it better that I did ;)
You should take a look at Javascript framework such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) , [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/), or [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) which make this easier for you!

**Edit 2**
I've [reupdated the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t743gzxm/6/) to fix `this.def` in the `playerDam` function

Comment: if you have the time do you mind explaining a little more in depth. I'm glad that this works but I want to know how so I can replicate and edit it if need be.

Comment: I don't really know where to get started with stuff like knockout and react.

Comment: You should first master JavaScript basics such as Objects, Arrays, scopes. After that, read  the documentations on and the examples on the librairies above. They are all very well written.