# Storing prompt as object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom

I am making a game that battles a monster when you click the button and the equation for damage is based on the player and monsters stats. I had help getting the object for the monster to work in the equation but I don't know how to get the Player object working properly because it isn't being stored as a select option.
Here is the post I made earlier, it will be easier to understand my code if you look at the answer here first[Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044922/how-to-call-on-an-objects-property-value-outside-of-the-object-maker/36045333?noredirect=1#comment59742599_36045333)

[Here is my current fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hou0m72/)

I need to be able to prompt the user for their username but still use their stats in the equation.

```
function Player(username, lvl, exp, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {
    var self = this;
    this.username = username;
    this.lvl = lvl;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.atk = atk;
    this.def = def;
    this.spd = spd;
    this.implement = function() {
        var h1 = document.getElementById('user');
        h1.innerText = this.username;
        h1.addClass('playerName');
        $(h1).data('player', self)
    }
    this.implement();
}
var newPlayer = new Player(prompt("What is your username?"), 1, 0, 0, 10, 2, 2, 2);
playerEl = $('.playerName');
player = playerEl.data('player');
```

Comment: `h1.addClass('playerName');` won't work as there is no `addClass` method for elemet

Comment: What is the real requirement.. what should happen? The entered name is displayed in the `user` element

Comment: but I have the variable h1.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5cdwu23d/3/ This is what the battle button and select menu should be doing

Comment: `addClass` method is for jQuery object, what you have is a dom element reference... `$('#user').text(this.username).addClass('playerName').data('player', self)`

Comment: Oh that works... I can't believe it was so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in adding the class `playerName`, `h1` is a dom element reference which does not have the `addClass` method.

Since you have jQuery, you can use

```
  this.implement = function() {
    $('#user').text(this.username).addClass('playerName').data('player', this)
  }
```